# I cannot change theme in Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110

Tags: google-chrome, themes

A few days ago I got this popup saying the my Chrome was out of date and demanded I upgrade. I did and got  Version 27.0.1453.110.

All my extensions disappeared as did any settings (like where to download to ) disappeared. The "theme" I as using disappeared. When I open Chrome now I get an initial screen that shows several link icons , facefook, new york times, etc. I can change the homepage but I have to hit the home icon to get there.

Finally I cannot reload the theme I had before this "upgrade" and cannot change the theme to any other I chhose. I can select a theme, it says it has added it but the theme will never appear.

I feel like there has been a hijack here somewhere. The way the upgrade screen came up was odd and since I am always forced into the same initial screen I get the feeling that something was added that is not really from Chrome. Hard to find out what the real current version is.

I tried using the inspect element and saw this being loaded http://buenosearch.com/

I have tried reloading and am ending up with the same thing.

Question really amounts to is this a legit version of Chrome and why can't I change the theme? Why is that page with all the links the only one that will start?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on "popup saying the my Chrome was out of date and demanded I upgrade?" In my experience, Chrome does not pop-up dialogs for updates.